# VIM as main text editor

Tags: vim

I've been struggling for hours on trying to make VIM my main code editor for scripting languages like python and php. Of course, I can open files with VIM, but how do I get nice formatting and syntax highlighting?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:syn on` in your `.vimrc` file. This should turn on Syntax Highlighting.

You probably also want `:set smartindent` which does a few automatic indent tricks for you.